# How to kill shiny app in ESS without killing R process

Tags: r, emacs, shiny, ess

Whenever I run a shiny app from ESS, it works, but I can't get the prompt back without killing the whole R session (like clicking the "Stop" button in RStudio).  The normal `Ctrl-C Cntrl-C`, or `Cntl-g` don't work.  So, I have to resort to `Cntrl-x k`.  How do I kill the shiny process without killing R?

Comment: Thanks so much for the question and the answer, I ignored this situation at first, but couldn't really work with shiny applications killing the whole process every time. THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I finally found out the reason. I had the option

```
(setq comint-prompt-read-only t)
```

set somewhere in my init files.  Apparently, when this option is set it becomes impossible (well, beyond me anyway) to send a kill signal to the R process.  I don't understand what is happening though.  If I run a server directly from `httpuv` I can kill it even with the option set, but not when running an app through `shiny`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
C-c C-c
```

in iESS to quit the shiny app.